# How to Mount HFS+ drive as read-write on startup

Tags: ubuntu, mount, usb-drive

I have a mac drive, HFS+ formatted, plugged into my ubuntu 20.04 machine. On startup, it mounts read-only, and I have to run the following script to get it to mount as a read-write drive.

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo umount /media/media/4tb1
sudo mount /dev/sdb2 /media/media/4tb
sudo mount -t hfsplus -o remount,force,rw /media/media/4tb
```

Can I get it to mount as read-write on boot? This is the info about the partition in Disks:
[image]
[image]
Thanks!!

Comment: Do you need to turn off journaling in the HFS - see https://superuser.com/questions/84446/how-to-mount-a-hfs-partition-in-ubuntu-as-read-write?

Comment: @MrR I am able to mount the drive as read-write with that script since I have installed hfsprogs. It doesn't seem like the drive configuration is the problem.

Comment: The fstab entry you show doesn't seem to be the correct one - that's your root disk (see it's ext4)?

Comment: Oh, good catch, I've updated the q with the info from disks.

Comment: Is it as simple as adding `,rw` on the line with `nosuid,nodev,nofail` and checking the _mount at system startup_ option?

Comment: Very nearly! I added force as well rw on that line and checked the box and it worked! Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 2):

The needed changes were:

1. checking the "Mount at system startup" box
2. adding "force, rw" to the options (4th) line
3. changing the mount point to the destination point of the initial script

The final fstab line is:

```
/dev/disk/by-id/usb-Seagate_Expansion+_Desk_NA8B0LGL-0:0-part2 /media/media/4tb auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show,force,rw 0 0
```